# How to use native library in another package on Android Play Store applications?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cpu

I want to put differently compiled native library packages (4 different packages having armv6, armv6+vfp, armv7, armv7+neon) on Play Store.

Then, I want to publish 1 main application package which can use one of those 4 packages. It will detect the cpu type in runtime and tell user to download application named MyAppLibPackARMV6vfp. Afterwards, if user tries to use the library in main application, main application will check if MyAppLibPackARMV6vfp is installed and if it is, then it (main app) must be able to load native library from that remote package.

This must somehow be possible as we see similar packages on Play Store like: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.ffmpeg.v6_vfp

How can I do the same thing; allowing a third party (made by me) application to use a library located on another application (made by me)?

Answer (score 1):

Just to post my opinion of how to achieve this goal. It might not the most standard way but it should work.

Take the MX player plugin for example, the main program is MXPlayer.apk and the addition codec is in MXPlugin.apk

Since these two are all signed by the same vendor, they can use the same UID. So MXPlugin could be able to copy the xxxCodec.so into /data/data/com.example.mxplayer/libs/ and then the MXPlayer could  be able to load the new codecs.

It is not very graceful. Taking your situation for example. If I were you, I would expose all the APIs in the main program via a service interface (and protected by the same signature). And all the other apk would bind to this main service and call the implementation in native library.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I am already using a service for all native operations. The only thing is, that service runs in the same process with my main process. (As I am aware that It is possible to make it run in a more seperate way... But I didn't do that as I had to write more complex code to do that)